# operand expected (Error token is "-") and ambiguous redirect

Tags: bash, unix

I have to errors, operand expected and ambiguous redirect.
Here's my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
read input >| inputfile
file_name=$(cut -d" " -f1 inputfile)
i=$(cut -d" " -f2 inputfile)
j=$(cut -d" " -f3 inputfile)
k=$(cut -d" " -f4 inputfile)
l=$(cut -d" " -f5 inputfile)
maxlinetoget=$[$l-$k]
currentlinecount=1
result=0
while read line
do
    if [ $currentlinecount -ge $k && $currentlinecount -le $l ]
    then
            echo -n $line >| linefile
            echo -n $line
            for number in linefile
            do
                    echo $number
                    result=$[$result+$number]
            done
    fi
    currentlinecount=$[$currentlinecount+1]
done < $file_name
echo $result
```

And the errors:

```
./P4.4: line 8: -: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "-")
./P4.4: line 24: $file_name: ambiguous redirect
```

line 8 is: `maxlinetoget=$[$l-$k]`
line 24 is: `done < $file_name`
I have no idea what's wrong, please tell me.

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly is the value of `file_name`?

Comment: Well, I thought it was F1, but appearently it is nothing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both errors are the result of the fact that neither `$l` not `$file_name` have a value. Bash sometimes produces mysterious error messages when unquoted variables are empty. (You would have gotten more sensible error messages if you'd used `$((l-k))` instead of the deprecated `$[$l-$k]`, or had quoted your substitutions, particularly `"$file_name"`.)

```
read line >| inputfile
```

reads one line from `stdin` and puts it in the variable `$line`. It produces no output, so `inputfile` is empty. Consequently, all of the following `cut` commands produce no output (nothing-in, nothing-out: the infamous NINO).

What you apparently wanted to do was

```
read file_name i j k l rest
((maxlinetoget = l - k))
# Or maxlinetoget=$((l-k))
```

Comment: Thanks, but now I have another error: `./P4.4: line 8: [: missing `]'
` 3 times. line 8 is this: ` if [ $currentlinecount -ge $k && $currentlinecount -le $l ]`

Comment: But I did, the $[...] was what I tought and I don't know if the system works with the new syntax (It's about 15 years old)

Comment: Ah. You should use `if ((currentlinecount >= k && currentlinecount <= l))`.

Comment: @shoham: Things change. Sometimes you need to teach yourself new tricks. Should be easy enough to tell if the bash you're using supports (( )) and $(( )); they've been around for a long time. The old style way requires a lot more quoting.

Comment: @shoham: By the way, you can't use `&&` inside `[ ... ]`. (You should have been taught that, too :) ). You can use it inside `(( ... ))`. In `[ ... ]` , you need to use `-a`.